# Select2 and JSON Data

Tags: json, xpages, jquery-select2

I am using select2 version 4 and I have a REST service control on an XPage, that reads the fullname column from the names.nsf.

I have the search working, but for some reason, I don't get a list of values back I can select.

The JSON object being returned, looks something like this:

```
[{"@entryid":"1376-E6D5EBE8ADBEFA7088257DF8006E4BA2","fullname":"Full Name\/OU\/O"},{"@entryid":"1375-FD1CB92A13BFD0E088257DE4006756D7","fullname":"Another Full Name\/OU\/O"}]
```

The code to initialize the select2 looks like this:

```
x$( "#{id:comboBox1}" ).select2({
  ajax: {
   url: "xJSON.xsp/names",
   dataType: 'json',
   delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      return {
      search:'[fullname=]*'+params.term+'*',       
      //  q: params.term, // search term
        page: params.page
      };
    },

    results: function (data, page){

    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
      // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to
      // alter the remote JSON data
      console.log(data);
      return {
        results: data
      };
    },
    cache: true
  },
  //escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; }, 
  minimumInputLength: 1
});
```

When I look at the browser's console, I can see that the search worked and JSON objects are being returned, however, I don't get a list of values to select from.

For the result return I've tried results: data.fullname and results: data, text:'fullname' but nothing happens.

What am I doing worng?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either switch your JSON response to include `id` and `text` for each object, or re-map them in your `processResults` method. [These two properties are required](https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html#changed-id) on all selectable objects now in Select2 4.0. Since I'm assuming you either can't change your JSON response, or it wouldn't make sense to, you can easily re-map the data with the following `processResults` method.

```
processResults: function (data) {
  var data = $.map(data, function (obj) {
    obj.id = obj.id || obj["@entityid"];
    obj.text = obj.text || obj.fullname;

    return obj;
  });

  return {
    results: data
  };
});
```

This will map the `@entityid` property to the `id` property and the `fullname` property to the `text` property. So selections will be sent to your server containing the `@entityid` and will be displayed using the `fullname`.

---

Also, the `results` method is no longer needed in Select2 4.0.  This was renamed to the current `processResults` method.

Comment: Hello Kevin, thank you so very much for your response. It worked. The only thing I had to change was to make fullname the obj.id as well in order to be able to select data from the result list. You are a lifesaver! Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code exactly as it is, and just changed the `fieldname` and the search query and worked out just fine.

This is my `JSON` looks like

```
[{"@entryid":"1482-AD112B834158AD0D80257E4B004EC42E","@unid":"AD112B834158AD0D80257E4B004EC42E","id":"Victor Hunter","text":"Odhran Patton"},{"@entryid":"1496-291F2480D806A91E80257E4B004EC3D2","@unid":"291F2480D806A91E80257E4B004EC3D2","id":"Wesley O'Meara","text":"Wesley O'Meara"},{"@entryid":"1421-CC19D06880F5DC2980257E4B004EC537","@unid":"CC19D06880F5DC2980257E4B004EC537","id":"Stephen Woods","text":"Emma Doherty"}]
```

What I know is that `select2` expects an **`id`**, and a **`text`** parameters from the `JSON`.